# How to create two instances of log4j logger in same class?

Tags: logging, log4j, sap-commerce-cloud

Im trying to create two instances of log4j logger in same class. This is to create another two log files from an existing log file.

Answer (score 3):

you can use this code:

```
Logger logger1 = Logger.getLogger("#HERE THE NAME OF APPENDER 1#");
Logger logger2 = Logger.getLogger("#HERE THE NAME OF APPENDER 2#");
...
logger1.debug("this log write in file 1!");
logger2.debug("this log write in file 2!");
```